# What event should be raised on "Hide Selected" for an aggregated model?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

What event should be raised when I select some object in the Viewer and choose "Hide selected" in the context menu for an aggregated model?

For a single model it is HIDE_EVENT but it isn't raised for an aggregated model. I also checked maybe there is another event, something like AGGREGATE_ISOLATION_CHANGED_EVENT but didn't find anything suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_HIDDEN_CHANGED_EVENT` instead for catching the hidden event in the model aggregation scenario.

To do similar as "Hide selected" in the context menu for an aggregated model, we can call APIs in this way:

```js
let selSet = viewer.getAggregateSelection();
viewer.impl.visibilityManager.aggregateHide(selSet);
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, I can't see this event in the "@types/forge-viewer": "^7.69.5"

Comment: Hi @olomakovskyi, APS Viewer (formerly Forge Viewer) is written in Pure JavaScript, and the types you mentioned a community-contributed version. You can contribute the missing part [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/forge-viewer) if you find any.